# How update records in the database and remove a table row on button click using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have created an HTML table with dynamic rows. On the end the every row there is a button. When that button on the particular row is clicked, the row needs to removed without page refresh.

So I'm trying to do it by changing the values of column in database on button click. There is a field named 'status' in my database, which is initially set  to 'unchecked'. But when I click the button, the update query is to be triggered hence changing the 'status' field to 'checked' on that particular row, and removing that particular.

**newCust.php**

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-light table- 
responsive text-nowrap">
<thead class="thead-dark">
<tr>
<th class="col"><label> nID</label></th>
<th class="col"><label> CUSTOMER NAME </label></th>
<th class="col"><label> ADDRESS </label></th>
<th class="col"><label> CITY </label></th>
<th class="col"><label> STATUS </label></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
<!-- GETTING DATA FROM THE TABLE WHERE STATUS FIELD IS UNCHECKED -->
$query = "select * from mx_newcustomer where status = 'unchecked'";
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$nID = $res['nID'];
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $nID;  ?></td>
<td><?php echo $res['customername'];  ?></td>
<td><?php echo $res['address'];  ?></td>
<td><?php echo $res['city'];  ?></td>
<td><button type="button" id="button<?php echo $nID;  ?>" class="btn btn- 
dark" >Ok</button></td>
</tr>

<script>
<!-- AJAX TO UPDATE RECORDS IN THE DATABASE-->
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#button<?php echo $nID ?>").click(function(){
alert('Test');
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "updateCust.php",

<--TRYING TO 
PASS THE CLICKED BUTTON ID. I BELIEVE THIS IS WHAT I'M DOING WRONG-->
data:  {"nID":$('#button<?php echo $nID ?>').serialize()}, 
success: function(response)
{
 alert("Record successfully updated");
}
});
});
});

</script>
```

**updateCust.php**

```
$db = mysqli_connect("credentials");
$nID = $_POST['nID'];
$query = "UPDATE mx_newcustomer SET status = 'checked' WHERE nID = 
'$nID'";
$res = mysqli_query($db, $query);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

I'm not getting any errors, but the update query is not being triggered either. The expected result is remove the table row whose button has been clicked, without the page being refreshed.

Comment: There may be no errors (that you know of), but what *is* happening when you debug?  Does this PHP code produce the HTML and JavaScript that you expect?  Is your button's click handler invoked?  Is the AJAX request made?  Does it contain the data you expect?  What is the server's response?  In your server-side code, what is the runtime value of `$query`?  What is the result of `mysqli_query`?  There's a lot of debugging you can do here.

Comment: Have you watched the request/response in the browser's developer tools?

Comment: I debugged it on chrome, but there was nothing on the console. Although I am getting a response, 'Record successfully updated'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `.serialize()`, it returns a string in the form `name=value`. But your button doesn't have a name or value, so there's nothing to serialize.

Change it to:

```
data:  {"nID": <?php echo $nID ?>},
```

To delete the row, you can use:

```
success: function() {
    $("#button<?php echo $nID?>").closest("tr").remove();
}
```

Comment: Hi made the change, and now the query is being updated in the database. Thank you. But the table row is not being removed on button click, but it is being removed on refresh. Kindly help me with that as well.

Comment: Sorry, `closest("td")` should have been `closest("tr")` to remove the whole row, not just one cell.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot Barmar. The code is working now. Appreciate it.